# How can one authenticate Dataloader CLI when instance has MFA enabled?

Tags: soap-api, data-loader, oauth, cli, mfa

Since moving my data export script out of my company's sandbox and into prod, I've been having a hard time getting Dataloader to authenticate, and I suspect this may be due to the Salesforce Authenticator (MFA) being turned on only for the production environment.

In the Dataloader GUI, if I choose Password Authentication and enter my {username} in Username and {password}{session token} in Password, I receive an error "This session is not valid for use with the API" [image: Dataloader GUI login error screen].

The same error occurs in Dataloader CLI.

```
   2022-03-21 18:00:04,460 ERROR [csvOppsExtractProcessEAProd] client.PartnerClient runOperation (PartnerClient.java:359) - Error while calling web service operation: describeSObject, error was:
com.sforce.soap.partner.fault.UnexpectedErrorFault: null
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584) ~[?:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:721) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:593) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.parseDetail(SoapConnection.java:250) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.createException(SoapConnection.java:224) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:163) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:108) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.describeSObject(PartnerConnection.java:1491) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient$10.run(PartnerClient.java:203) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient$10.run(PartnerClient.java:195) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient.runOperation(PartnerClient.java:354) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient.describeSObject(PartnerClient.java:759) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient.setFieldTypes(PartnerClient.java:711) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.setFieldTypes(Controller.java:199) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:157) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.runBatchMode(ProcessRunner.java:262) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.runBatchMode(ProcessRunner.java:246) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:104) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
2022-03-21 18:00:04,481 FATAL [main] process.ProcessRunner logErrorAndExitProcess (ProcessRunner.java:238) - Unable to run process
java.lang.RuntimeException: This session is not valid for use with the API
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:179) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.runBatchMode(ProcessRunner.java:262) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.runBatchMode(ProcessRunner.java:246) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.DataLoaderRunner.main(DataLoaderRunner.java:104) [dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
Caused by: com.sforce.soap.partner.fault.UnexpectedErrorFault
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584) ~[?:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:721) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:593) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.parseDetail(SoapConnection.java:250) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.createException(SoapConnection.java:224) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:163) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:108) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection.describeSObject(PartnerConnection.java:1491) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient$10.run(PartnerClient.java:203) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient$10.run(PartnerClient.java:195) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient.runOperation(PartnerClient.java:354) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient.describeSObject(PartnerClient.java:759) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.client.PartnerClient.setFieldTypes(PartnerClient.java:711) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.controller.Controller.setFieldTypes(Controller.java:199) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        at com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner.run(ProcessRunner.java:157) ~[dataloader-54.0.0-uber.jar:?]
        ... 3 more
```

However, if I use Postman and login directly to the SOAP API with the same credentials, I get a Status 200 OK. Since Dataloader is using SOAP for the Bulk API under the hood, I'm not totally sure why this would happen.

[image: Postman connects Status 200 OK using same credentials]

What am I missing here? Is there a better way to set up the session programmatically before using Dataloader, and to maybe bring that in elsewhere? I tried playing around with different endpoints in the config.properties but didn't get anywhere

**More background info:**

- Our organization primarily uses SSO, but I have had our administrator set up a username and password for me, since to my knowledge SSO is not currently supported by Dataloader CLI.
- I am able to successfully login to the Dataloader GUI using the web-based OAuth flow, but this requires me to approve the login using MFA which isn't practical for a server script.
- My user profile, my role has "API Enabled" checked, "Manage Multi-Factor Authentication in API" unchecked, and"Multi-Factor Authentication for API Logins" unchecked.
- Under Managed Packages within my user profile, I see "Dataloader_P5r_oauth" and "Dataloader_Partner" came pre-installed, both with Status = Free.
- My role's session settings are High Assurance for "Session Security Level Required at Login", which I've seen elsewhere may be the root of the problem but IT would like to keep security as tight as possible if there's another workaround

Comment: Can you enable the "Multi-Factor Authentication for API Logins" permission at your profile and try to login. check this article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_require_2fa_api.htm&type=5

Comment: You have to choose oAuth to see MFA. Unfortunately the CLI flavor of DataLoader doesn't do oAuth. While technically possible, DataLoader didn't implement it. Your only option with CLI is user/pwd. Thus, you'll have to claim this user account is exempt from MFA under _System Integration Login Types via the API_ rubric. See [MFA FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000352937&type=1) for more info, consult lawyers for caveat emptor protection. Plan B: load data via `sfdx`, it is CLI + oAuth capable.

Comment: Thanks for the help! IT made a new role for me and disabled High Assurance just on that, which works as expected. I didn't use `sfdx` because of the export batch size limitations, but presumably there's a way to loop through multiple batches?